# CakePHP redirect form post with querystring

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm a Cake newbie, and I'm looking to post a querystring value into a controller method, but always reload the view with the querystring intact. Currently I have the below snippet.

```
public function something()
{
     if($this->request->query !=null )
        $date = $this->request->query["date"];

}

<?php echo $this->Form->create('setup',array('action' => 'something?date=2013','id'=>'setup-form','role'=>'form') ); ?>
```

Any advice on why something() doesn't redirect to something?date=2013 on its default render? Do I need to do some special routing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CakePHP 2, you can include query string parameters in `$url` parameters like so:

```
array('action' => 'something', '?' => array('date' => '2013'))
```

CakePHP will build the query string and append it to the matched URL in your routing configuration.

(Note: You may need to pass `FormHelper::create` an entire URL, generated from [`HtmlHelper::url`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url), instead of using the "shorthand" technique.)